# Why are these characters no longer acquaintances of Peter Parker?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home* (2021),

> Strange casts a spell to make everybody forget Peter Parker is Spider-Man.

However, the characters (at the end of the film)

> Ned and MJ still talk to each other, but seem to have no memory of Peter Parker at all.

Why is this? Ned at least was Peter's best friend even before he found out that Peter Parker was Spider-Man. And MJ seemed to at least know Peter Parker as an acquaintance. But,

> when Peter walks into the coffee shop that MJ works at and sees MJ and Ned, he tells MJ his name and she has no recognition. And Ned sees him but does not react as if he knows him.

Why are these characters no longer friends, or at least acquaintances, of Peter Parker?

Comment: Because everyone's forgotten about Peter, even where it makes no logical sense.

Comment: Strange did not cast a spell to "make everybody forget Peter Parker is Spider-Man", he cast a spell to make everyone forget Peter Parker.

Comment: Evidence to back that up?

Comment: I can accept that as an answer as long as it's correct, obviously

Comment: agree @mrp - which seems kind of odd really

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a transcript of the explanation of the questioned event, which seems to generally match my recollection:

> So cast a new spell. **But this time, make everyone forget who Peter Parker is. Make everyone forget... Me.**
>  No.
>  But it would work, right?
>  Yeah, it would work. **But you got to understand, that would mean everyone, who knows and loves you We'd... We'd have no memory of you. It'll be as though you never existed.**
>  I know. Do it.

They understood “everyone” means everyone. That’s how it was explained to work.

Comment: Oh, I see. So they didn't forget that Peter Parker was Spider-Man, they just forgot him. Makes sense

Comment: @PeterNielsen I mean, those who knew he was Spider-Man (which was a lot of America and probably the world after _Far From Home_) _also_ forgot that he was Spider-Man, and probably the fact that they knew who Spider-Man was.

Comment: It would also include Drax, Star-Lord, and Mantis, as well as Nick Fury (offworld) and the Skrulls who were standing in for him and Hill. It'll be interesting to see if Strange's spell affected them.